# C# call C function with FILE* parameter

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I have the following function pointer defined in a struct in a C library:

```
struct SOME_STRUCT {
    [...]
    uint8_t(*printinfo) (SOME_STRUCT * ss, FILE * hFile);
    [...]
}
```

This function writes some data to the file handle hFile, and I want to call it from C#. In C# I have:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    [...]
    public printinfoDelegate printinfo;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate byte printinfoDelegate(IntPtr ss, IntPtr hFile);
    [...]
}
```

I use the following code to call the function:

```
SomeStruct sStruct = [...];
String output;

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(tmpFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
    IntPtr structPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(sStruct));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(sStruct, structPtr, false);

    byte result = sStruct.printinfo(structPtr, stream.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle());

    stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
    {
        output = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

But I cant get it to work. I Suspect that the problem is that I can't just pass the handle from the filestream as a FILE*. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: A FILE* isn´t just handle. Import another C function which gives you a FILE* from a filename (and another one to close it again). Ie. a wrapper for fopen and fclose.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct, a .net filestream has nothing to do with a FILE*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handles in .NET refer to Win32 `HANDLE` (or `HINSTANCE` and many more), e.g. the one returned by the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. A `FILE *` on the other hand is a part of the C runtime library, and returned by a call to the `fopen` function.

So if you want to use that function which takes a `FILE *` parameter then you'll have to P/Invoke the `fopen` method too, like in [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msvcrt.fopen).

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no way to marshal a FileStream as a FILE*. If you need the stream only inside the C function, you could create the handle by callind fdopen().

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare wrappers for `fopen` and `fclose`. What you need is something like this:

```
public static class LegacyFileManager
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr fopen(String filename, String mode);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern Int32 fclose(IntPtr file);
}
```

Then in your code:

```
IntPtr fileHandle = LegacyFileManager.fopen(tmpFileName, "r+");

// your logic here

LegacyFileManager.fclose(fileHandle);
```